# jQuery Mobile Shortcuts

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've recently been learning jQuery Mobile but have a hard time remembering all the possible parameters and the general structure of all the components.  Is there anything that can help with this rather than sheer memorization?  (I'm using Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own code snippets for this.  It's pretty nice.  You just type a few characters (jqmPage, jqmToggle, etc.) and you get the whole structure.

**Blog Post**

I’ve been recently learning jQuery Mobile and am really impressed with the technology. It is a powerful and robust tool to quickly create content for mobile devices. However, with it being so new to me and with it being so robust, I find it difficult to remember all of the syntax for the many different things you can do with it. It occurred to me that code snippets could be a great way to relieve this burden, so I began creating my own to do this.

As an example, using my jqmPage code snippet (by typing

```
<div id="PAGENAME" data-role="page" data-theme="THEME">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar" data-theme="a">
        <h4>FOOTER</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

To download all the snippets, please check out [jQuery Mobile Code Snippets](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/jquery-mobile-code-snippets-for-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

1. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html
2. http://www.cheatography.com/danielschmitz/cheat-sheets/jquery-mobile/

I just bookmark the docs and refer to them often till it gets memorized. Also Dreamweaver cs 5.5 + has some helpful code completion and hints for jquery mobile.